# Latin equivalent for "case-by-case" phrase

Tags: synonyms, latin, business-language

I would appreciate a reminder of the Latin-phrase equivalent, or alternative suggestions, for "*case-by-case*," specifically for language to be included in a public-private case-study.  Thank you.

Comment: _Seriatim_ can have one meaning of _case by case_, but that doesn't seem to be the sense you're looking for. If  you could use it in a sentence we might have some idea what that is.

Comment: @alexanderjsingleton "on an individual case basis"?  https://books.google.com.br/books?id=zDQ5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA884&lpg=PA884&dq=%22on+an+individual+case+basis%22&source=bl&ots=9wSJ9NZYLJ&sig=4aepPpuecHeMGYKnoBM6-G7aoNw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwA2oVChMI-ueGtPP-yAIVCz8UCh3SIAaf#v=onepage&q=%22on%20an%20individual%20case%20basis%22&f=false

Comment: @JohnLawler, That's it-thank you for the reminder, sir!  Though I would appreciate additional contributions from others, please feel free to post as an answer.

Comment: Another non-Latin option could be "[on a **case-specific** basis](http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/on+a+case-specific+basis.html)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see question-comments contributing to my selection of "*seriatim*" for the following sentence beginning a section within my study:

"**Matters Seriatim**: The NDAA-2014 renewal enumerated compliance orders for national electronic medical data standards in February 2015."(6)

Answer (score 1):

***ad hoc***
means "for this" 
as in: "The decision of this case is meant to apply only to this case."

In a sentence:

> In regard to the matter of risks posed to persons or property off of a defendant's real property by natural conditions on that land possessor's property, this Court has decided to address each case on an *ad hoc* basis.